# default timeout in wso2 api-manager? how to increase it?

Tags: timeout, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created few API's in wso2 api manager. My back end services sometimes respond in 5-8 seconds or will take up to max of 50 seconds.
What is the default timeout for wso2 apis?
I checked this file- passthru-http.properties.
It has the following content:

```
## This file contains the configuration parameters used by the Pass-through HTTP transport
## Nhttp tuning parameters 
#http.socket.timeout=60000
#http.connection.timeout=0
#http.socket.buffer-size=8192
#http.socket.linger=-1
#http.nio.select-interval=1000
#http.tcp.nodelay=true
#http.connection.stalecheck=false
#http.socket.reuseaddr=false
```

if i uncomment this line - http.socket.timeout=60000 , will the default time out becomes 60 seconds?

will their be any major performance impacts if i increase the defualt timeout up to 60 seconds?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article showing what needs to be edited in order increase the timeout period in APIM.

[How to increase timeout](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-increase-time-out-value-in-wso2.html)

If you backend services take much time, it would be advisable to check on them first and improve them a bit.